# How to get the next id from the array when paging?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a button that turns the pages. I need to remain in this component, change the ID in the address bar and thus I will change the information on the site. Data coming to me, look like this:

```
{
 "users": [
  {
   "id": "3135",
   "name": "Lulu"
  },
 {
  "id": "8173",
  "name": "Lala"
 },
 {
  "id": "5783",
  "name": "Lolo"
 }
]
```

I am outputting detailed information about the user by getting an id. My navigation has looks like:

```
{ path: 'list', component: ListComponent },
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/list ', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'details/:id', component: DetailComponent }
```

I have a button, by pressing which the transition from '/details/Id' to 'details/nextId'. But this button does not work. This is a request for the next ID in the service. (I get the data from Database API​)

```
private users: User[] = new Array<User>();
private locator = (u: User, id: number) => u.id === id;
getNextId(id: number): number {
 let index = this.users.findIndex(u => this.locator(u, id));
 if (index > -1) {
  return this.users[this.users.length > index + 2
   ? index + 1 : 0].id;
 } else {
  return id || 0;
 }}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="next-user" [routerLink]="['details', userService.getNextId(user.id)]" routerLinkActive="active">
    Next User
  </button>
```

DetailsListComponent:

```
 private userService: UserService,
private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
private location: Location,
private router: Router) {

activeRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.detail = params['details'] === 'details';
  let id = params['id'];
  if (id !== null) {
    Object.assign(this.user, userService.getNextId(id));
  }
});
}
detail: boolean = true;
```

I searched the Internet and here the answer to this question, but found only suitable for php. Please, help me. What am I doing wrong? I just recently began to study angular 7 and do not always understand what to do.

I do not know how to explain it correctly, how to explain my problem. But I will try, I have a page that displays a list of my users. Clicking on the user opens a new page with more detailed information about it. In order not to go back to the page with a list of users and not to select the next user, a page with detailed information about the user assumes the presence of the Next button. When I click on this button, the array is iterated, it is determined by which ID the page is currently open and which ID is the next in this array, after which the page goes to the next ID. That is, the same page is opened, but the information on it is about another user who is following the list after the previous user.
But my button is currently not working and I do not understand why.

Comment: Can you post your html

Comment: Can you please specify what exactly you mean by doesn't work? Is there some error or wrong id, etc?

Comment: There are no errors in the IDE terminal or the console. How many do not press the button, nothing changes.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I updated the answer have a look.

Comment: @LillyZhuk did you try ?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand what issue you are facing exactly but here is an overview of how you can route to next User id by clicking on button.

```js
// in Component.ts file
// import Router from @angular/router
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


constructor(private _router: Router){}

// to get the next user id
getNextId(id: number): number {
       
       // write your logic to get the next id here 
    
 }}
 
//navigate to user id 
getNextUser(id:number){

let nextId  = this.getNextId(id); // holds next id 

this._router.navigate([`/register-step2/${nextId}`]);

}
```

```html
<!-- In Component.html  -->
<div class="userDetails">
 <p> {{user.name}} </p>
  <p> {{user.age}} </p>
   <p> {{user.occuption}} </p>
</div>
<button class="next-user" (click)="getNextUser(user.id)">
    Next Movie
  </button>
```

I assumed that for each userid service gets called and the result of the service is stored on `user` variable.  I Hope it helps .

Answer (score 1):

=== EDIT (After the question was clarified) ===

Now I understand your use case. Here is how I would go about it.

Few things to note so that the example is clear:

1. `list` route was renamed to `users` (makes more sense to me)
2. Brand new `UsersComponent` is created to handle all the users-related routes
3. `DetailComponent` -> `UserDetailsComponent`
4. `ListComponent` -> `UsersListComponent`

Those are just my coding conventions so that things are clear. You can leave your naming style.

In your root component, you will have your root `<router-outlet>`. And you will also have another `<router-outlet>` in `UsersComponent`.
In your router settings you would have:

```js
{ path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, children: [
  { path: '', component: UsersListComponent }
  { path: ':id', component: UserDetailsComponent }
] },
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/users ', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Notice, I added a new component `UsersComponent` which will be a parent for both `UsersListComponent` and `UserDetailsComponent`. It will hold a `<router-outlet>` that will hold either `UsersListComponent` or `UserDetailsComponent` depending on the child route that is active.

1. For `/users` it will render `UsersListComponent`.
2. For `/users/:id` it will render `UserDetailsComponent`.

So, `UsersListComponent` will have something like the following template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let user of users" class="user-list-item" >
    <p>user.name</p>
    <button class="open-user-details"
            [routerLink]="['/users', user.id]">
      Navigate To Details
    </button>
</div>
```

In `UserDetailsComponent` you will have something like the following:

```html
<div class="userDetails">
  <p> {{user.id}} </p>
  <p> {{user.name}} </p>
  <p> {{user.age}} </p>
  <p> {{user.occuption}} </p>
</div>

<button class="next-user" 
        [routerLink]="['/users', getNextUserId()]" 
        routerLinkActive="active">
    Next User
</button>
```

And in `.ts` file for `UserDetailsComponent` you would have:

```js
user: User; // complete user details object. ID included
constructor(private userService: UserService,
            private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute)

// gets the next user id based on the current user.id
public getNextUserId(): number {
  return this.userService.getNextId(this.user.id)
}

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.activeRoute.params.pipe(switchMap((params) => {
        return this.userService.getUserById(params.id);
    })).subscribe(user => {
        this.user = user;
    });
}
```

I assume your `UserService` has separate methods:

1. `getNextId(curId: number): number`
2. `getUserById(userId: number): Observable<User>`

Comment: I have separate methods:

Comment: 1.  `getNextId(id: number): number {
    let index = this.users.findIndex(user => user.id === id);
    if (index > -1) {
      return this.users[this.users.length > index + 2
        ? index + 1 : 0].id;
    } else {
      return id || 0;
    }
  }`

2. `getUserById(id: number): Observable<User> {
    return this.getUsers()
      .pipe(
        map(users => users.find(user => user.id === id)));
  }`
I used your code, but an error occurred
error TS2322: Type 'Observable<User>' is not assignable to type 'User'. Property 'page' is missing in type 'Observable<User>'.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. since `getUserById` returns an Observable, you should use `switchMap` here. To switch from `params` Observable to `User` Observable. I updated the answer.

Comment: Next time make sure you give all the necessary information straight away, though.

Comment: It doesn't work(((
**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**

Comment: I think problem in service.ts. It returns  not the next ID, but the current one.